# git removes server generated files in tracked directory

Tags: git

Let's assume this basic project:

```
├── css
│   ├── custom.css
│   └── main.css
└── index.html
```

In the root of this directory the following commands are run:

```
git init
git add -A :/
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push ssh://username@servername:path/to/www master
```

This deploys the first commit to the server so it has the same directory structure. The file `custom.css` is intended for someone with access to the server (via ftp) to be able to edit as they need to. So I need it set up so whenever a push is made that the `custom.css` file isn't overwritten by the version on my local. So I run the following commands:

```
echo css/custom.css >> .gitignore
git rm --cached css/custom.css
git commit -am "removed custom.css from being tracked"
git push ssh://username@servername:path/to/www master
```

However this just removes the `custom.css` file from it's location rather than leaving it untouched. How can I set it up so when pushing git doesn't overwrite or remove `custom.css` without having to configure anything serverside? I'm hoping for a solution that involves configuring the local git repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.gitignore` is a global method of ignoring a file, which means it won't be tracked at all.  If you need to ignore files locally, but you do not want the repository to ignore the file, you should commit the `custom.css` file then create a local explicit repository exclude by using a `.git/info/exclude` [as described in the git documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/).

That said, I think the best practice would be to set up a watcher on the server (for example a grunt worker or a cron job running at regular intervals) to watch for changes to the files on the server and commit them as they are made, since this will provide you with proper version control over the `custom.css` file and allow rollbacks if necessary. (Depending on your particular situation, this may be overkill, in which case, just go with the explicit exclude.)

If you decide to go that route, you should probably maintain the git repository in a separate directory from the production site.  Configure a grunt worker to watch the production site, so when the FTP user makes changes it will trigger a commit to the repository. One way you could accomplish this would be by using [grunt-git-commit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-git-commit) in combination with [grunt-git-deploy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-git-deploy) being triggered by a [grunt-contrib-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-watch) task.

Comment: thanks for your reply but I can't use any solution that involves server-side configuration. also using your solution involving a local explicit repository exclude seemed promising however upon following your instructions what happens is whenever I push git deploys the version of the custom.css file that exists in the repo and overwrites the custom.css file on the server (I'm using a webhook to deploy to a server I don't control). i need the custom.css file to remain untouched when a git push happens because someone else is editing it via ftp on the server. Hope this helps clarify. Thank you

Comment: The grunt worker, cron job, or whatever doesn't specifically need to happen on the server.  You could configure something on your local machine to watch the FTP server for changes.  The easiest way would be to not exclude the file from the project, but set up a local script that diffs the FTP version against your local `custom.css` before you push a commit.  If the FTP version is different from your copy, make the script overwrite your copy with what is on the server and commit it along with whatever changes you have made.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah and thanks for clarifying but I was hoping for a simpler solution - some config done in my local git repo. I take it there's no solution like that available?

Comment: Probably not.  You're trying to include the file in the repository, but you don't want the repository to be in charge of the file.  It's counter-intuitive.  Either the repository is in charge of the file, or the FTP user is in charge of the file.  You can't have both without using a solution like the ones I've offered you.